# Maps and Flatmaps in Scala

Tags: scala

I am new to scala. I need a lot of help with using maps and flatmaps with tuples.

I have functions as follows-

```
    def extract(url: String): String = {//some code}
    def splitstring(content: String): Array[String]={//some code}
    def SentenceDetect(paragraph: Array[String]): Array[String] = {//some code}
    def getMd5(literal: String): String = {//some code}
```

I have a incoming list of urls. and I want it to go through above series of functions using map and flatmaps.

```
    var extracted_content=url_list.map(url => (url,extract(url)))

    val trimmed_content=extracted_content.map(t => (t._1,splitstring(t._2)))

    val sentences=trimmed_content.map(t => (t._1,SentenceDetect(t._2)))

    val hashed_values=sentences.flatMap(t => (t._1,getMd5(t._2)))
```

The issue is I am getting at error at flatMap as type mismatch--

```
Error:(68, 46) type mismatch;
  found   : (String, String)
  required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
val hashed_values=sentences.flatMap(t => (t._1,getMd5(t._2.toString)))
```

How to get it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're after.

```
val hashed_values = sentences.map(t => (t._1, t._2.map(getMd5)))
```

This should result in type `List[(String,Array[String])]`. This assumes that you actually want the Md5 calculation of each element in the `t._2` array.

Recall that the signature of `flatMap()` is `flatMap(f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B])`, in other words, it takes a function that takes an element and returns a collection of transitioned elements. A tuple, `(String,String)`, is not `GenTraversableOnce` thus the error you're getting.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted exactly this.

Answer (score -2):

You are getting this error because `getMd5(...)` accepts a string, however `sentences` is of type `List[(String, Array[String])]` (assuming `url_list` is `List[String]`), so `t._2` is of type `Array[String]`.

Anyway, some notes regarding your code:

1. variable names in scala are "lower camel" (https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html), not lower-with-underscore
2. `extracted_content` should probably be a `val`
3. since all your variables are maps, and since you want to transform the map's value, you better use `.mapValues` instead of `.map`

Comment: Parameters are not a problem as far as I know. I tried to changing that. Doesn't help. it has got to do something with the the context which flatMap accepts.
Also, thanks for the extra notes. I edited my code accordingly.